# Is there any jquery plugin similar to lazyload for content

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I'm searching for jquery pluging where I can showing 3 table based record and on scrolling it should make ajax request for next 3-10 record. similar to lazyload but for content. any code snippet even help me.

Comment: It is easy enough to write yourself, why not go that route?

Comment: I'm beginner, can u suggest in code.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
           // The scrollbar is at the bottom of the screen
           // Do your ajax call here and populate a div.
        }
});
```